# Create custom controls without generic.xaml?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, custom-controls

I'm going crazy with different XAML designer errors in my PRISM application. 
I have custom controls inside Infrastructure project and it seems that all referencing projects have issue loading control template at some point.

Everything runs good at runtime but VS2010 just doesn't work with all kind of errors.
I know for sure it is related to custom control not properly loading style from generic.xaml for some reason.

What I want to try is to drop `generic.xaml` all together and switch to use named templates for my custom controls. This way I can always merge resource files so VS know where to look for stuff.

1. Do you think this is viable solution?
2. How do I populate `DefaultStyleKey` from named style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a viable solution: custom controls pull their information from Themes/generic.xaml. This is baked into the runtime.

If you're building a WPF/Silverlight composite application, you'll need to put your generic.xaml in your WPF project and link it to your Silverlight project.  That's the reverse of Prism guidance, but is required due to a bug with linked XAML files that are not at the root level in WPF projects.

Answer (score 0):

Without generic.xaml, it is some what difficult but with help of generic.xaml you can switch to use named templates for your custom controls. just simply adding following code in generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/CPMS.Utility.Controls;component/Controls/MyUc/Style/DBLoginForm.xaml" />

</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```